# How can I get my errors (in BindingResult) to bind to my fields?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have implemented custom validation for my JSP forms and when there are errors the form is returned with my errors bound to the BindingResult.  My form looks like:

```
<form:form name="createCustomer" action="/practicemvc/customers/create/" method="POST" modelAttribute="customerBean">

    <form:errors />

    <label for="customerName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="customerName" value="${customerBean.name}" />
    <form:errors path="name" />
```

The errors are displayed through:

```
<form:errors />
```

But, they are not being displayed through:

```
<form:errors path="name" />
```

My errors are merged to the BindingResult with:

```
for(ErrorType errorType: validationResult.getErrors()) {
    bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError(errorType.getProperty(),
            new String[]{errorType.getErrorCode()}, null, null));
}
```

getProperty() will return "name", and getErrorCode() returns the "INVALID_EMAIL".  "INVALID_EMAIL" translates to "Your email is invalid" through my messageSource bean.  If I look at the contents of the errors in my BindingResult, everything seems ok, but they are not outputting as expected in my JSP.  Any ideas?

Thanks, B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, to associate error message with a field you need a [`FieldError`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html), where `objectName` is `customerBean` and `field` is the field name.

Comment: be CareFull to have objectName like the commandName in the form, and like the className. See : http://ansaurus.com/question/1363753-spring-mvc-tag-doesnt-find-error-messages

Comment: but *field* has not getter

Answer (score 0):

Its seems I can get this to work with the following, but doesn't seem very neet.

```
for(ErrorType errorType: validationResult.getErrors()) {
    fieldErrorCodes = new String[]{
        errorType.getErrorCode()
    };

    bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError(errorType.getProperty(), fieldErrorCodes , null, null));

    if(errorType.getProperty().length() > 0) {
        bindingResult.addError(new FieldError(bindingResult.getObjectName(), errorType.getProperty(), null,
                false, fieldErrorCodes, null, null));
    }
}
```